# Calling a function in a JavaScript file with Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, selenium

So, I'm running these Selenium IDE tests against a site I'm working on.  Everything about the tests themselves is running fine, except I would like to do a bit of clean-up once I'm done.  In my MVC3 Razor based site, I have a JavaScript file with a function that gets a JsonResult from a Controller of mine.  That Controller handles the database clean-up that Selenium IDE otherwise couldn't handle.

However, I'm having a hard time finding any sort of documentation on how to do this.  I know I can do `JavaScript{ myJavascriptGoesHere }` as one of the Values for a line in the test, but I can't seem to find a way to tell it to go find my clean-up function.

Is it even possible for Selenium IDE to do this sort of thing?

If it comes down to it, I can just make a separate View to handle the clean-up, but I'd *really* like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute your own JavaScript function that exists in your test page from Selenium IDE, you need to make sure you access it via the window object.  If you look at the reference for `storeEval` for instance, it says:

> Note that, by default, the snippet will run in the context of the
>   "selenium" object itself, so this will refer to the Selenium object.
>   Use window to refer to the window of your application, e.g.
>   window.document.getElementById('foo')

So if you have your own function e.g. `myFunc()`.  You need to refer to it as `window.myFunc()`.

This can be very handy for exercising client-side validation without actually submitting the form, e.g. if you want to test a variety of invalid and valid form field values.

If you use `runScript`, that should already run in the window's context.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("myJavascriptGoesHere");
```

Make sure your javascript works first before using it here!

Answer (score 0):

Actually to access your page javascript space, you need to get the real window of your page : this.browserbot.getUserWindow()

See this statement to get the jQuery entry point in your page (if it has jQuery of course ^^ )

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887281/2143734