# Get element property with JQuery selector and Selenium IDE 2.0.0

Tags: jquery, selenium, properties, ide, selector

I've got a webpage that selects a custom-made Raphael radio button immediately after the page loads. I'm trying to verify that the appropriate id is selected using Selenium IDE 2.0.0 and FireFox 20.0.1.

I've tried the following...

```
|getEval | javascript{selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery('.response-options.selected').prop('id')} | |
```

...but I simply get null as a result. As a test, I've tried...

```
|getEval | javascript{selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery('#item-responses-A1_1a_No').prop('id')} | |
```

...but I still get null, even though I can run...

```
|assertElementPresent | #item-responses-A1_1a_No | |
```

...and pass. Interestingly, if I run...

```
|getEval | javascript{selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery('.response-options.selected')} | |
```

...(without the .prop('id')), I get an "object Object".

Does anyone know how to get an element property with a JQuery selector? I've seen solutions posted that involve a user-extensions.js helper function, but it seems like that is really just a convenience function that lets you use JQuery selectors using less text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assertEval is what you're looking for.  First though, you'll have to store a reference to the jquery using a store command earlier on.

Here is an example:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery</td>
    <td>jq</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertEval</td>
    <td>${jq}('.response-options.selected').prop('id')</td>
    <td>**the name of the ID you want to match against**</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps others, I wanted to just run javascript (including jquery statements in my page) and the accepted answer (1000s kudos to you Scottingham !) is the starting point. You just have to redefine $ sign with jQuery from getUserWindow !

Then add a runScript command, with in the target the following :

```
javascript{var $=this.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery; ... your javascript there}
```

For example

```
javascript{var $=this.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery; $('#myid').click();}
```

and remember that selenium only sees  what is ctually visible on the page... and so do your jquery selectors in that context