# Selenium IDE: Call JavaScript function from application page

Tags: function, call, selenium-ide

Running Selenium IDE 3.17.0 in Chrome.

I want to execute a JavaScript function in the page I am testing.

I didn't find a way to have "executeScript" access functions.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Same here, i also tried `run script`, but without success

Comment: Same goes trying to access the function by as a property of `window` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11410123/8965861)